DNS configuration for Apache multisite
I have a friend for whom I set up a website on my publicly-accessible server; however, I'm having a lot of trouble getting DNS to work properly.

I added a file/entry for the new site in /etc/apache2/sites-available and the name of the domain to /etc/hosts. Browsing to the site locally works fine, as does sticking it into a subdirectory under my webroot and going to https://mydomain/subdir.

I'm serving several domains from Apache already; however, all of these belong to me and are registered at a single domain provider (https://godaddy.com). The registrar for my friend's domain, however, is different - https://internic.co.il - and this seems to be where I'm running into a problem.

I've changed the nameservers at her domain provider to point to the GoDaddy nameservers, and added an A record pointing to the IP of my box -
A   xxxxxxxx.co.il  209.59.180.101  600 seconds


to my primary domain. Waited a while (at this point, it's been a day), and... nope, doesn't resolve. 'dig' gives me a 'SERVFAIL'; 'ping' says 'Temporary failure in name resolution'.
Clearly, I don't understand what the heck I'm doing... so I'm turning to you experts. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

You need to tell GoDaddy that it is authoritative for your friend's domain; or you need to have her registrar provide that service. GoDaddy generally won't publish a DNS record for a domain that it hasn't been told about. So you'd need to go into "My Products", "DNS", and add her domain as one of yours. GoDaddy will then give you two of their nameservers, which you would enter into Internic as being the authoritative nameservers for that domain. Alternately, you could tell Internic that it was responsible for the DNS, and put the A record there.

Thanks for your response. Internic says "The zone of this domain has no records or it is not managed by us, if you think it's an error please contact our support team", and has nothing other than fields for nameservers. The closest thing I can find to what you suggest is "Manage My Products"/"DNS" - and there's no option to add a domain; it's just a listing of the ones I own.

On the left side of the screen when you're in "Manage my products | DNS | Manage all" you should also have an entry "Services". Drop that down and select "DNS Hosting". There is an "Add DNS Hosting" option there, that should do what you need to do.
